# How to export a table dataframe in PySpark to csv?

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, export-to-csv

I am using Spark 1.3.1 (PySpark) and I have generated a table using a SQL query. I now have an object that is a `DataFrame`. I want to export this `DataFrame` object (I have called it "table") to a csv file so I can manipulate it and plot the columns. How do I export the `DataFrame` "table" to a csv file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 261, accepted):

If data frame fits in a driver memory and you want to save to local files system you can convert [Spark DataFrame](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L42) to local [Pandas DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) using [`toPandas`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py#L1229) method and then simply use `to_csv`:

```
df.toPandas().to_csv('mycsv.csv')
```

Otherwise you can use [spark-csv](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv):

- Spark 1.3

  ```
  df.save('mycsv.csv', 'com.databricks.spark.csv')
  ```
- Spark 1.4+

  ```
  df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save('mycsv.csv')
  ```

In Spark 2.0+ you can use `csv` data source directly:

```
df.write.csv('mycsv.csv')
```

Comment: Super answer. For the first option, if I want to write to a pipe-delimited file rather than comma-delimited CSV, is this possible?

Comment: If you have spark dataframes you can use `df.write.csv('/tmp/lookatme/')` and that will drop a set of csv files in `/tmp/lookatme`
Using spark is significantly faster than serializing it in pandas. The only drawback is that you'll end up with a set of csvs instead of a single one and if the destination tool doesn't know how to concatenate them you will need to do it yourself.

Comment: What a big deal it is to get a csv out of spark. Something interesting about that first solution is that `to_csv` works without needing to import Pandas. `.toPandas` is part of Spark maybe it implicitly imports it..

Comment: You should be able to use `df.coalesce(1).write.csv('mycsv.csv')` if you insist on having a single output file

Comment: @Txangel thanks for your answer. However, when I use that it runs without any error but I can't find *any* csv created in the target location. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Rotail [That's because it is not how this works in general](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51603898/10938362).

Comment: This is for an RDD dataframe right? As opposed to an SQL dataframe? I think the author wanted something for the latter, which I do not see in this solution.

Comment: using ```df.write.csv('mycsv.csv')``` exports the csv to hdfs environment. How can i get it in my local environment?

Comment: @Tracy exact same question that I've been having. Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: @etjk, you can copy a directory from hdfs to a local dir with:
hdfs dfs -copyToLocal <input> <output>

Comment: Note that to `toPandas` may actually change your schema e.g. an int column containing null values will end up a float column in pandas (with NaNs). The actual integers e.g. "100" will be written out as "100.0".

Answer (score 47):

For Apache Spark 2+, in order to save dataframe into single csv file. Use following command

```
query.repartition(1).write.csv("cc_out.csv", sep='|')
```

Here `1` indicate that I need one partition of csv only. you can change it according to your requirements.

Comment: As indicated here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.repartition it is recommended to use coalesce() instead of repartition() to increase performance ("If you are decreasing the number of partitions in this RDD, consider using coalesce, which can avoid performing a shuffle.")

Comment: @Seastar: While coalescing might have advantages in several use cases, your comment does not apply in this special case. If you want to have a .csv in your hdfs (or whatever), you will usually want one file and not dozens of files spreaded across your cluster (the whole sense of doing `repartition(1)`. You need to shuffle the data for this either way, so coalescing will not help at all in the bigger picture.

Answer (score 21):

If you cannot use spark-csv, you can do the following:

```
df.rdd.map(lambda x: ",".join(map(str, x))).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("file.csv")
```

If you need to handle strings with linebreaks or comma that will not work. Use this:

```
import csv
import cStringIO

def row2csv(row):
    buffer = cStringIO.StringIO()
    writer = csv.writer(buffer)
    writer.writerow([str(s).encode("utf-8") for s in row])
    buffer.seek(0)
    return buffer.read().strip()

df.rdd.map(row2csv).coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile("file.csv")
```

Answer (score 12):

You need to repartition the Dataframe in a single partition and then define the format, path and other parameter to the file in Unix file system format and here you go,

```
df.repartition(1).write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').save("/path/to/file/myfile.csv",header = 'true')
```

Read more about the [repartition function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.repartition)
Read more about the [save function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save)

However, repartition is a costly function and toPandas() is worst. Try using .coalesce(1) instead of .repartition(1) in previous syntax for better performance.

Read more on [repartition vs coalesce functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31610971/spark-repartition-vs-coalesce).

Answer (score 9):

**Using PySpark**

Easiest way to write in csv in Spark 3.0+

```
sdf.write.csv("/path/to/csv/data.csv")
```

this can generate multiple files based on the number of spark nodes you are using. In case you want to get it in a single file use repartition.

```
sdf.repartition(1).write.csv("/path/to/csv/data.csv")
```

**Using Pandas**

If your data is not too much and can be held in the local python, then you can make use of pandas too

```
sdf.toPandas().to_csv("/path/to/csv/data.csv", index=False)
```

**Using Koalas**

```
sdf.to_koalas().to_csv("/path/to/csv/data.csv", index=False)
```

Comment: omg I have been looking for something like `.repartition(1)` for HOURS to write into only 1 csv file thank you so so so much!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: please upvote if that helped you )

Comment: already did :-)

Comment: this is the correct answer. the others are 5 years old at least.

Answer (score 4):

How about this (in case you don't want a one liner) ?

```
for row in df.collect():
    d = row.asDict()
    s = "%d\t%s\t%s\n" % (d["int_column"], d["string_column"], d["string_column"])
    f.write(s)
```

f is an opened file descriptor. Also the separator is a TAB char, but it's easy to change to whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
'''
I am late to the pary but: this will let me rename the file, move it to a desired directory and delete the unwanted additional directory spark made
'''

import shutil
import os
import glob

path = 'test_write'
#write single csv
students.repartition(1).write.csv(path)

#rename and relocate the csv
shutil.move(glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '\\' + path + '\\' + r'*.csv')[0], os.getcwd()+ '\\' + path+ '.csv')

#remove additional directory
shutil.rmtree(os.getcwd()+'\\'+path)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the method with pandas and this gave me horrible performance. In the end it took so long that I stopped to look for another method.

If you are looking for a way to write to one csv instead of multiple csv's this would be what you are looking for:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv("train_dataset_processed", header=True)
```

It reduced processing my dataset from 2+ hours to 2 minutes

Answer (score 0):

try display(df) and use the download option in the results. Please note: only 1 million rows can be downloaded with this option but its really quick.