# cannnot copy CSV to REDSHIFT

Tags: csv, amazon-redshift

I converted dataframe to csv

```
df.write.format('com.databricks.spark.csv')\
    .option("inferSchema", "true")\
    .option("delimiter", "|") \
    .save('res.csv')
```

Above code generates a partitioned csv file. 'res.csv' is a directory that contains several files (.*SUCCESS*.crc, .part-xxxxx.crc)

I uploaded the res.csv to s3(s3://path). And then I tried to copy the res.csv to REDSHIFT using copy command.

```
copy tableName from 's3://path' 
CREDENTIALS  'aws_access_key_id=************;aws_secret_access_key=*********** 
delimiter '|'
```

but it doesnot work with following error. I got this error from table 'stl_load_errors'

> 100   1   165722  2016-07-29
>   21:43:42  7490    1968765 s3://r630166/res.csv.gz/._SUCCESS.crc
>   1  0 crc
>   1216  Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x63 found at location 2**
>
> 100   0   165722  2016-07-29 21:43:42 7490    1968765 s3://r630166/res.csv.gz/.part-00000.crc   1 0
>   crc
>   1216  Missing newline: Unexpected character 0x63 found at location 2

copy commands work when I point to the exact file inside res.csv directory which has data in it

Comment: At first step when I generated csv from dataframe, I thought res.csv would be a file. Is there a way I can generate convert a dataframe to normal csv file

Comment: Does this help? [how to export a table dataframe in pyspark to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385363/how-to-export-a-table-dataframe-in-pyspark-to-csv)

Comment: No. I tried it already. thanks