# Writing a big Spark Dataframe into a csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv, apache-spark

I'm using Spark 2.3 and I need to save a Spark Dataframe into a csv file and I'm looking for a better way to do it.. looking over related/similar questions, I found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385363/how-to-export-a-table-dataframe-in-pyspark-to-csv), but I need a more specific:

If the DataFrame is too big, how can I avoid using Pandas? Because I used `toCSV()` function (code below) and it produced:

> Out Of Memory error (could not allocate memory).

Is directly writing to a csv using file I/O a better way? Can it preserve the separators?

Using `df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv('mycsv.csv')` will cause the header to be written in each file and when the files are merged, it will have headers in the middle. Am I wrong?

Using spark `write` and then hadoop `getmerge` is better than using coalesce from the point of performance?

```
def toCSV(spark_df, n=None, save_csv=None, csv_sep=',', csv_quote='"'):
        """get spark_df from hadoop and save to a csv file

        Parameters
        ----------
        spark_df: incoming dataframe
        n: number of rows to get
        save_csv=None: filename for exported csv

        Returns
        -------

        """

        # use the more robust method
        # set temp names
        tmpfilename = save_csv or (wfu.random_filename() + '.csv')
        tmpfoldername = wfu.random_filename()
        print n
        # write sparkdf to hadoop, get n rows if specified
        if n:
            spark_df.limit(n).write.csv(tmpfoldername, sep=csv_sep, quote=csv_quote)
        else:
            spark_df.write.csv(tmpfoldername, sep=csv_sep, quote=csv_quote)

        # get merge file from hadoop
        HDFSUtil.getmerge(tmpfoldername, tmpfilename)
        HDFSUtil.rmdir(tmpfoldername)

        # read into pandas df, remove tmp csv file
        pd_df = pd.read_csv(tmpfilename, names=spark_df.columns, sep=csv_sep, quotechar=csv_quote)
        os.remove(tmpfilename)

        # re-write the csv file with header!
        if save_csv is not None:
            pd_df.to_csv(save_csv, sep=csv_sep, quotechar=csv_quote)
```

Comment: It would make more sense if you reduce the function to represent essential functionality you want to implement. Asking _how can I avoid using Pandas_ when function returns `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` make no sense.

Comment: The function goal is to save the spark dataframe into a csv file.. sorry I will remove the return.

Answer (score 0):

> If the DataFrame is too big, how can I avoid using Pandas?

You can just save the file to HDFS or S3 or whichever distributed storage you have.

> Is directly writing to a csv using file I/O a better way? Can it
>   preserve the separators?

If you mean by that to save file to local storage - it will still cause OOM exception, since you will need to move all data in memory on local machine to do it.

> Using df.coalesce(1).write.option("header", "true").csv('mycsv.csv')
>   will cause the header to be written in each file and when the files
>   are merged, it will have headers in the middle. Am I wrong?

In this case you will have only 1 file (since you do `coalesce(1)`). So you don't need to care about headers. Instead - you should care about memory on the executors - you might get OOM on the executor since all the data will be moved to that executor.

> Using spark write and then hadoop getmerge is better than using
>   coalesce from the point of performance?

Definitely better (but don't use `coalesce()`). Spark will efficiently write data to storage, then HDFS will duplicate data and after that getmerge will be able to efficiently read data from the nodes and merge it.

Comment: Actually, I'm saving to HDFS (that's what the getmerge does isn't it?), but I need to have it 1 csv file locally to use it in further operations.. so that I don't have to repeat reading it from HDFS which is expensive..

Comment: `hadoop fs -getmerge [-nl] <src> <localdst>` - it takes directory in HDFS and meges all files into one on local file system as per docs [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#getmerge).

Answer (score 0):

We used databricks library . It works fine

```
df.save("com.databricks.spark.csv", SaveMode.Overwrite, Map("delimiter" -> delim, "nullValue" -> "-", "path" -> tempFPath))
```

Library :

```
<!-- spark df to csv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: does it work even for spark 2.x versions? I thought it's only for spark 1.x

Comment: for spark 2, add spark-cav to your classpath, then go df.write.format("csv").save(path)