# missed column when create a temporary table Pyspark SQl context

Tags: pyspark

I create a temporary "country" table from dataframe whcih contains all the rows were  : `country_code_destination` is null:

```
df_country=df.where(df.country_code_destination.isNull()).registerTempTable("country")
```

Then, I would like to export this temptable into a csv file :

```
%%sql -q -o qry_country
SELECT * FROM country

%%local
qry_country.to_csv("country_code_null.csv", sep=';')
```

But the problem is that in the "country_code_null.csv" file, i do not find the "country_code_destination" column. There is all the column except the "country_code_destination".

Any idea to help to resolve this problem please?

Thanks

Comment: %%local and %%sql are not in the same environment. Try rebooting your notebook, and re-run your queries, you will figure out the problem

Comment: @Steven , always the same problem.. is there any other method to export to a csv file a spark dataframe? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to export a table dataframe in PySpark to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385363/how-to-export-a-table-dataframe-in-pyspark-to-csv)