# How to access nested attribute without passing parent attribute in pyspark json

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to access inner attributes of following json using pyspark

```
[
 {
    "432": [
        {
            "atttr1": null,
            "atttr2": "7DG6",
            "id":432,
            "score": 100
        }
    ]
},
 {
    "238": [
        {
            "atttr1": null,
            "atttr2": "7SS8",
            "id":432,
            "score": 100
        }
    ]
}
]
```

In the output, I am looking for something like below in form of csv
atttr1, atttr2,id,score
null,"7DG6",432,100
null,"7SS8",238,100

I understand I can get these details like below but I don't want to pass 432 or 238 in lambda expression as in bigger json this(italic one) will vary. I want to iterate over all available values.

```
print(inputDF.rdd.map(lambda x:(x['*432*'])).first())
print(inputDF.rdd.map(lambda x:(x['*238*'])).first())
```

I also tried registering a temp table with the name "test" but it gave an error with message element._id doesn't exist.

```
inputDF.registerTempTable("test")
srdd2 = spark.sql("select element._id from test limit 1")
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. I am using spark 2.4

Comment: what is `peopleDF`? Could you show the output of `peopleDF.show()`?

Comment: that's input df. Renamed it. Also the output .show() is 

+--------------------+--------------------+
|                 238|                 432|
+--------------------+--------------------+
|                null|[[, 7DG6, 432, 100]]|
|[[, 7SS8, 432, 100]]|                null|
+--------------------+--------------------+

Answer (score 1):

Without using pyspark features, you can do it like this:

```py
data = json.loads(json_str)  # or whatever way you're getting the data

columns = 'atttr1 atttr2 id score'.split()
print(','.join(columns))  # headers

for item in data:
    for obj in list(item.values())[0]:  # since each list has only one object
        print(','.join(str(obj[col]) for col in columns))
```

Output:

```
atttr1,atttr2,id,score
None,7DG6,432,100
None,7SS8,432,100
```

Or

```py
for item in data:
    obj = list(item.values())[0][0]  # since the object is the one and only item in list
    print(','.join(str(obj[col]) for col in columns))
```

FYI, you can store those in a variable or write it out to csv instead of/and also printing it.

And if you're just looking to dump that to csv, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31386290/1431750).