# Export Multiple GB PySpark dataframe to CSV, np or pickle

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have this large dataset around 6gb and have processed and cleaned the data using PySpark and now want to save it so I can use it elsewhere for machine learning uses

I am trying to find the fastest way of saving the datasets.
I followed this link, but its taking so long to save the csv or the parquet.
[How to export a table dataframe in PySpark to csv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31385363/how-to-export-a-table-dataframe-in-pyspark-to-csv)

Please can someone provide some information on how I can do this

Comment: csv is probably not a good format for such a large dataset, parquet would be much better

Comment: I tried following the tutorial from the link in my question but still takes so long to follow it. Using this code:
`scaled.withColumn("par_id",col('col_1')%50). \
 repartition(50, 'col_1').write.format('parquet'). \
 save("/saveFolder")`